# How to make a search function with dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, filter, webshop

I have a website with a lot of products I've made in Wordpress. To make it easy for my visitors, I would like to make a search function with dropdowns.

My idea is, that my visitors have to select some categories in some dropdowns, and eventually press a search button to then display products that matching, what the visitors had chosen.

These types of dropdowns I think are like thise: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to create a custom dropdown and not select list. ALternatively you can use `datalist`

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!

So, now I know how to make the dropdowns, and I also know how to set it up, so it looks nice. I also know how to set it up, so it looks nice, but how can I transfer my visitors to the right place on my website?